# small program on struts2 and  jsp

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

i have done some learning on struts based on one project that i got.Now i have to build 2 to 3 struts jsp pages.

I have following scenario..

```
<action name="BackAction" class="ClassnamePath">
<result name="user_validated" type="redirectAction">
                <param name="actionName">welcome</param>
            </result>
<result name="user_profile_found_in_database">/resources/userprofile.jsp</result>
```

what does param will tell..what is the significance of param(i do not know about this)

my scenario is like this In the class(ClassnamePath) i have done one java program which bring the data from the database and put the values in the userprofile.java(for example the userprofile has variable members like name,email,phone,pin)
that values are come from database and stored in the object of the class userprofile.

i have a task that whenever the result "user_profile_found_in_database" has been done those values should be presented in the jsp as result of the "user_profile_found_in_database"

Is the result "user_profile_found_in_database"  that i mentioned in the action tag correct?

the jsp page should be having userprofile with labels as the fields of the userprofile and values should be in the text boxes.

i do not know anything about jsp pages...even web programming..but i am learning on my own..(i am having one doubt how jsp pages are different from struts jsp pages)
with the above tasks i can learn lot in struts and jsp..

Please give some knowledge on this to build further.

Comment: It will be very hard to learn about Struts (or any Front Controller) without learning Servlets and JSP first. You should start from the basics, then move to Struts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSP pages are not way different than simple JSP pages and in short Struts2 will provides a set of tags which will help we as an end developer to build application fast as these tags provides a easy to access functionality about various features S2 providing, few of them are

1. Accessing Value Stack using OGNL
2. Data conversion from server to client and other way around
3. Features to access other things like request/response/session in most easy and flexible way.

In end when you browser will render the jsp page it will be simple HTML and S2 tags one using in there application will be converted to the HTML as browser will understand HTML.

regarding second part accessing user profile in your jsp do the following gin your Action class

1. Create an instance of UserProfile in you action class
2. Create getter and setter for the UserProfile instance
3. Fill the value in the user-profile (you will fetch that from your DB call)

when your action will send back the response, S2 will place the user-profile instance on top of Value stack and we can access its properties using S2 tags like

```
<s:textfield name="user_name" value="%{name}"/>
<s:textfield name="user_age" value="%{age}"/>
```

here `name` and `age` are the properties of your user-profile.`param` in your `redirectAction` configuration is being used to provide parameters to the result, for more information about what parameters do please read official document.

- [redirect-action-result](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/redirect-action-result.html)

.

Answer (score 0):

Ya i got your question like this,

> what is the exact meaning of param tag?

param tag means:

Struts 2 “param” tag is used to parametrize other tags. However, when you declared the “param” tag, the “parameter value” can be define in two ways :

1. “value” attribute
2. Text between the start and end of “param” tag.

For Example:

```
<param name="fruit">Banana</param> 
<param name="fruit" value="Banana"/>
```

In Your example the 1st case i think

Here see this web site it is present complete structure...

http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-param-tag-example/